# Page navigation in ICEFaces

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, icefaces

I recently started working on JSF in ICEFaces FrameWork(Server # Glassfish). 
I have one question.

In my first JSF page i have radio buttons, If i to select  and click on next page, I have to publish those selected values in my second page. If i click on back button , i have to show the selected values in my first page.

How can i achieve this? Please suggest

My First Page(suites.xhtml).

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">
<ui:param name="title" value="Eclipse Template Test Page" />
<ui:param name="companyName" value="Autoexetc" />
<ui:define name="menuItems">
    <ace:menuItem value="Dashboard" url="/dashboard.jsf" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-home"
        styleClass="menuBarItem" />
    <ace:menuItem value="Suites" url="/suites.jsf" styleClass="menuBarItem" />
    <ace:menuItem value="Status" url="/status.jsf" styleClass="menuBarItem" />
    <ace:menuItem value="Report" url="#" styleClass="menuBarItem" />
    <ace:menuItem value="Terminal" url="#" styleClass="menuBarItem" />
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="tabItems">
 Your in Suites Page <h:commandButton value="Back To DashBoard" action="dashboard" />
 <br></br>
  1. Hard-coded with "f:selectItem" : 
    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{user.favColor1}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Red" itemLabel="Color1 - Red" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Green" itemLabel="Color1 - Green" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Blue" itemLabel="Color1 - Blue" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>

    <br />

        2. Generated by Map :
    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{user.favColor2}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{user.favColor2Value}" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>

        <br />

         3. Generated by Object array and iterate with var :
    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{user.favColor3}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{user.favColor3Value}" var="c"
        itemLabel="#{c.colorLabel}" itemValue="#{c.colorValue}" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>

        <br />

            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="status" />
    <h:commandButton value="Reset" type="reset" />
</ui:define>

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

And My Result Page (status.Xhtml), which gives my selected values.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">
<ui:param name="title" value="Eclipse Template Test Page" />
<ui:param name="companyName" value="Autoexetc" />
<ui:define name="menuItems">
    <ace:menuItem value="Dashboard" url="/dashboard.jsf" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-home"
        styleClass="menuBarItem" />
    <ace:menuItem value="Suites" url="/suites.jsf" styleClass="menuBarItem" />
    <ace:menuItem value="Status" url="/status.jsf" styleClass="menuBarItem" />
    <ace:menuItem value="Report" url="#" styleClass="menuBarItem" />
    <ace:menuItem value="Terminal" url="#" styleClass="menuBarItem" />
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="tabItems">
 Your in status Page <h:commandButton value="Back To suites" action="suites" />
 <br/>

<ol>
        <li>user.favColor1 : #{user.favColor1}</li>
        <li>user.favColor2 : #{user.favColor2}</li>
        <li>user.favColor3 : #{user.favColor3}</li>
    </ol>
</ui:define>
```

When i click on back button from my result page,  first page will display with selected values, if i re-select any values and submit it, cant able to navigate to my result page.

Comment: It would really help us suggest solutions if you include your code (i.e. your JSF page) so we know what you have tried so far. JSF pages do not have variables; you probably have some backing bean with java code that you should include as-well.

Comment: Hi , I was using [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-checkboxes-example/) for page navigation. But cant able to find the code for back button(When clicked, to show the selected values in my first page).

Comment: There is just a submit button on this page which will post the selected values into the bean `UserBean`. The bean is `@SessionScoped` which means that you can use it on the next page and the values will be available.

Comment: i have edited my question. Please check.

Comment: Your `suites` page has a submit button with `action="status"`. However your results page is named `Status.Xhtml` which is wrong: the name should be `status` (so it matches the action) and the extension should be `xhtml` so JSF will handle it (notice the case, unless it's a typo on your post and not your filename)

Comment: its a typo, i edited it.
I was able to select the values and display it in result page but When i click on back button from my result page, first page will display with selected values, But if i re-select any values and submit it, can't able to navigate to my result page.